# How to exploit the constraint structure of this optimization problem?

Tags: calculus, optimization, contest-math

I am having a contest math problem that look like this:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {\min }\limits_{x,y,z \ge 0} }&{x + 2{y^2} + \frac{3}{{{z^3}}}}\\
{{c_1}}&{1 \le z \le 1 - \left( {x + y} \right)}\\
{{c_2}}&{0 \le y \le 1 - x}\\
{{c_3}}&{0 \le x \le 1}
\end{array}$

It seems to me that the constraint look very nice since it look like I can back substitute the value of $x$ into $y$ and the value of $x$ and $y$ into $z$.

Beyond that, I am not sure how to proceed with this problem.

Please help me with this,

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 3 constraints, we deduce:
$$
x + 2y^2 + \frac{3}{{{z^3}}} \ge \underbrace{x + 2y^2 + \underbrace{\frac{3}{{{(1-x-y)^3}}}}_{\text{increasing in $y$}}}_{:=f(x,y)\ge f(x,0)} \ge \underbrace{x+ \underbrace{\frac{3}{(1 - x)^3}}_{\text{increasing in $x$}}}_{:=g(x)\ge g(0)} \ge 3\\
$$
We conclude that the minimum of the expression is $3$ and the minimum is reached if and only if $(x,y,z) = (0,0,1)$.

Comment: So the order of constraint that we should exploit is $c_1$ first, $c_2$ second and $c_3$ third right ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Exactly.

Comment: Is there anyway of solving this but do not use derivative ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Yes, in fact, the derivative is not necessary. Here is a better proof.

Comment: Oh damn can you present both of the approach. Please dont delete your old answer. I love both of them

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh In fact, the approach with derivatives (to prove the increase of the functionss $f$ and $g$) is really overkill.

Comment: Why does the $y$ disappear in the final step. It is a bit too fast ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh In fact, we have

$$f(x,y) \ge f(x,0) = \underbrace{x+ \underbrace{\frac{3}{(1 - x)^3}}_{\text{increasing in $x$}}}_{:=g(x)}$$
and  because 
$$g(x) \ge g(0) = 3$$
You will have the minimum of $3$.
The increase of the two functions $f(x,y)$ (in function of $y$) and $g(x)$ is straightforward and so derivative is overkill.